# Why there is no verb in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I came across a line that reads: 
**The options were limited. The alternatives unattractive.**

Why there is no verb **"were"** after the word alternative? Shouldn't it be **The alternatives *were* unattractive** ?

Comment: What part of "should" could possibly apply here? It’s an utterance. Not a sentence. So what?

Comment: Some sentences aren't really sentences. Like this one. Right?

Comment: I would use a comma or a colon after 'limited', rather than a period, myself.

Answer (score 4):

The verb is understood to exist. It is an advanced grammar style and acceptable when not over used. High school english teachers may or may not accept "understood" verbs. Often "understood" or appropriately dropping a verb is meant to emphasize the sentence.

This form is more often used in speaking than writing.

Comment: It's an example of "elision." It's the same thing as saying *the apples, oranges, and pears* instead of (saying) *the apples, the oranges, and the pears.* In fact, many sentences sound better *with* missing words than without—simply because that's what we're used to.

Comment: Although, in the specific case of the example in the question, I would likely style the second sentence with a comma, and write *The alternatives, unattractive*.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I have seen this kind of sentences many times while reading books and had tried to use it in my own English class writings. However, my ESL teacher told me it is wrong and it really frustrated me because I just SAW it in a book!

Comment: In this case I think "the alternatives unattractive" is way more likely in writing or a written speech. It's a sort of poetic way of speaking that most people don't spontaneously emit.